# How to add TestFlight beta app invitation from email

Tags: ios, testflight

I have test flight installed on my iOS 8.1 device (iPhone 5C), and an email invitation to join a beta release of an application on TestFlight. The email has the "Open in Test Flight >" button and the apple ID it was sent for matches the apple ID logged into TestFlight on the device.

When I press the button I am redirected to a website on my Chrome browser app, which redirects me immediately to the App Store page for TestFlight. Thats it. No app is added. If I open test flight, the app is not there.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Copy the link and open it in Safari?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the shiny new TestFlight app just automatically updated apps available for that user?  It's a little tedious maintaining email accounts on every test device just to click the link. (Or messing around to put the link on the device some other way.)

Comment: If you open the invitation email in Safari on your iPhone (I happen to use Gmail, so there's a quality web mail interface.), the link goes straight to TestFlight's "Install" screen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. I have installed `TestFlight` in my iPhone 6 device and also opened app invitation mail in Safari browser. But while I am accepting app invitation by clicking on `'Open app in TestFlight'` button, it was opening TestFlight app on App Store with open button. After click on Open button , TestFlight iOS app was opened with no apps.

After did researching found solution as, configured your mail in Apple Mail client and accept invitation from there. Now TestFlight app will be open with your app.

I know this is very late to reply your question but may this will be helpful for others. :)

Comment: Aahh... This is ridiculous man! How can they be so mean to us developers and just wreck everything... Every step of this new system is a pain...

Answer (score 14):

The solution is to get the link to open in safari and not in chrome.

Answer (score 6):

no need to remove any apps or installing your mail in Apple Mail.
In your desktop gmail, right click on the link ("Open in TestFlight") and copy link address.

Open a new mail and paste the link - send it back to your self.

Now, on your phone, open gmail app and copy paste the link in Safari. Enter!

Buona fortuna!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it doesn't work at all in Mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can only get consistent results by going to my email client through Safari browser and clicking the link. I removed Chrome browser and go the link through my Gmail app, but it just decided to default to the iOS mail app which was useless as it doesn't show a URL.

Quite broken really, and updating in the TestFlight app (which shouldn't be possible if it's not going to actually update) does nothing as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced same issue, you can resolve it by using any of the following steps :

- click the link from apple native email client (not gmail or inbox)
- open email on safari browser (not chrome)
- or on desktop right click on email and copy address and use that link.